# Last post in loop - custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I added the below code to my index.php and it's working fine. Then I added it to my type-[post_type].php file and it's still displaying the code for the last post on the page. I can't figure out why. Should I be doing it a different way?

```
    <?php if( $wp_query->current_post < $wp_query->post_count-1 ): ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fezhr.png" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is my loop for one of the post types:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<div id="content">
    <div id="latestLinks">
        <div id="listHead">Latest</div>
        <div id="listLinks"><a href="http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/" id="linksA">EVERYTHING</a> | <a href="http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/games/" id="linksG">GAMES</a> | <a href="http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/entertainment/" id="linksE">ENTERTAINMENT</a> | <a href="http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/tech/" id="linksT">TECH</a> | <a href="http://www.flesheatingzipper.com/podcasts/" id="linksP">PODCASTS</a></div>
        <br style="clear:both;" />
    </div>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="postWrapper">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1> 

            <div class="postDetails">
                <div class="postDetailsLeft">Posted by: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> on <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></div>
                <div class="postDetailsRight"><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?> | <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></a></div>
                <br style="clear:both;" />
            </div>

        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'large', true);
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" title="' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '"><img src="' . $image_url[0] . '" title="' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '" alt="' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '" class="aligncenter" /></a>';
        }
        ?>

        <?php
           ob_start();
           the_content('Read the rest of this article...');
           $postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', ob_get_contents());
           ob_end_clean();
           echo $postOutput;
        ?>
        <br style="clear:both;" />
        </div>
        <?php if( $wp_query->current_post < $wp_query->post_count-1 ): ?>
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fezhr.png" class="fezHR" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>


            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>



    <?php else : ?>
<div id="content">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/FEZ404.png" /><br /><br />
        <p>God dammit! FEZ why do you always ruin all the fun. Sorry the page you requested has been eaten! You will just have to find something else, deal with it.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your template file should be named `archive-[post_type].php`. Check out [the template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Comment: I know the codex says that but when I change them it goes back to using index.php.

Comment: Lemme just confirm a few things - the code you provided is used in 'the loop' to print an image, so long as it's not the last post? And you're trying to replicate this in a template file for a custom post type? When you tried `type-[post_type].php`, are you *sure* that file was used (and not `index.php`) when you viewed the custom post type archive?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using a template redirect in my functions.php file to find those type-[post_type].php. I don't understand why it wouldn't work still. Also I am 100% sure that it was using index.php even after taking the code out from my functions.php.

Comment: Could you post a little more code? Perhaps a sample of your loop?

Comment: Updated with my loop code in the original post. BTW, I have temporarily fixed with jQuery, just don't want it to be permanent.

Comment: Hmm, all I can suggest right now is a to do a little 'debuggin' - i.e. dump the `$wp_query` object before and after the loop, echo `$wp_query->current_post` inside the loop, and see if that highlights the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with it some more. Also if my code looks bad that's because I'm not a programmer, learning stuff slowly so I'm not very good right now.

Comment: What's weird is my original code works in the taxonomy.php and search.php just not in the type-[post_type].php or archive-[post_type].php. Could this be a bug?